# Does cURL open two connections (outgoing and incoming)?

Tags: curl, wget

Someone recently told me "Curl, wget, etc will open 2 http connects (out and in) plus the script so it’s less efficient generally."

From the *Everything cURL* book, I read that FTP via curl utilizes two connections but beyond that can't determine if there is any truth to the previous statement regarding HTTP.

Is it true that for a basic HTTP cURL task, two connections are created?

Comment: `Is it true that for a basic HTTP cURL task, two connections are created?` - no, this is bull. libcurl can do it via curl_multi or the likes if you explicitly tell it to, but curl by itself doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP requires only a single connection to fetch the content of a URL.  This is true regardless of whether the program doing the fetch is Curl, Wget, a browser or some other program.

FTP makes two connections to transfer a file.  It uses one long-lived connection for "control" activities (logging in, listing directories, requesting a transfer, ...) and makes a second separate connection to perform the actual data transfer.  This is a characteristic of the protocol, so again it apples regardless of whether the program is Curl, Wget, a browser or some other program.